# How to simulate key press (left / right Windows key) on button click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to simulate a key press to create a button click event.

After clicking the button in the Unity UI, the keys should be pressed 2 times (key_down, key_up 2 times)(with a small time gap (milliseconds) in between, so the start menu will open and close very fast without being noticed.

How can I do this in Unity for a UI button click.

E.g. When I press any UI button (in unity or winforms) I want to simulate a key press e.g. on a button click the combination of Ctrl+ ESC virtual key will be pressed and start menu will open

Answer (score 0):

Check it out here Maybe it helps https://answers.unity.com/questions/588786/is-it-possible-to-simulate-a-keypressinput-in-code.html?childToView=958624#answer-958624

Comment: I have already checked this, I want to write my own code instead of using this Library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `Input.GetKeyDown` and `Input.GetKeyUp` inside an if statement? I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you try to explain it in a little more detail?

Comment: When I press any UI button (in unity or winforms) I want to simulate a key press e.g. on a button click the combination of Ctrl+ ESC virtual key will be pressed and start menu will open.

Comment: why would you want to simulate the key press? just put the function you want to run in the onclick part of the button.